# The view account.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: django, web

Good day everyone, i'm new to django, i'm working on a project were users can create accounts, i'm using the django registration model. Here's the problem,during registration, if the username the guest wants to use is taken or the passwords entered don't match, it gives this error 'The view account.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.' instead of informing the guest about the errors.

**views.py**

```
def register(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)        
        if user_form.is_valid():            
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet            
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)            
            # # Set the chosen password                             
            new_user.set_password(                
            user_form.cleaned_data['password'])            
            # Save the User object            
            new_user.save() 
            profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)            
            return render(request, 'account/register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user})
    else:        
         user_form = UserRegistrationForm()    
         return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

Comment: There is no `else` for your inner `if` clause, so the method may return `None` when the `form` is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`Selcuk`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011147/selcuk) suggested in the comment, add an `else` clause in your `views` as below,

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet            
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            # # Set the chosen password                             
            new_user.set_password(
                user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            # Save the User object            
            new_user.save()
            profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
            return render(request, 'account/register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user})
        else:  # form is not valid
            return HttpResponse("Form is not valid")
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

Comment: Is there any way in the template(html file) to check if there was any `HttpResponse`? Like in PHP, I was doing `isset()`, is there something similar to this function in DJango 3.2 ?